# need to compress daily rotated jboss server logs and remove 15 days old file

Tags: jboss, logrotate

I have daily rotated jboss server log files and I need to compress them on daily basis and remove all 15 days old zipped files.

These are how my logs look now:

Please help me with exact code to put under /etc/logrotate.d

```
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 jboss jboss    725462 Sep  9 14:14 server.log.2020-09-09
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 jboss jboss   1106353 Sep 10 12:44 server.log.2020-09-10
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 jboss jboss    114741 Sep 15 04:15 server.log.2020-09-15
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 jboss jboss    670181 Sep 22 15:46 server.log.2020-09-22
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 jboss jboss    115057 Sep 29 05:14 server.log.2020-09-29
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 jboss jboss    553603 Sep 30 14:13 server.log.2020-09-30
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 jboss jboss    113213 Oct  6 04:57 server.log
```

Comment: What version of WildFly or JBoss EAP are you using?

Comment: @James R. Perkins, jboss EAP 6.4